# Custom button with downgrade to angularjs creates nested button (button is nested in new Angular)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-7

I have this custom button:

Html template:

```
<button mat-button
        [color]="color"
        (cbClick)="onClick($event)"
        [disabled]="disabled"
        [ngClass]="isStroked ? 'mat-stroked-button' : 'mat-raised-button'">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

Typescript:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'cb-button',
    templateUrl: './button.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss']
})
export class ButtonComponent {
    /**
     * Warning - calling this "click" causes bug due to naming conflict
     */
    @Output() public readonly clicked = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    @Output() public readonly popupClick = new EventEmitter();
    @Input() public color = 'primary';
    @Input() public disabled = false;
    @Input() public isStroked = false;
    @Input() public popup?: Popup;

    constructor() { }

    public readonly onClick = (event: MouseEvent): void => {
        this.clicked.emit(true);
    };

    public readonly onPopupClick = (event: MouseEvent): void =>{
        this.popupClick?.emit(event);
    };
}
```

using it:

```
        <span fxFlex></span>
        <cb-button class="cb-margin"
                   (clicked)="generateUserSecurityReport()">
            User Security Report
        </cb-button>
```

For some reason in one area of my app, but not in other areas, it is displaying with 2 buttons. When I remove `<ng-content>` it doesn't create 2 buttons:

[image]

Why is it nesting a second button in some scenarios?

EDIT:

HTML produced:

```
<cb-button _ngcontent-wwl-c684="" class="cb-margin" _nghost-wwl-c681="" ng-version="11.0.7">
    <button _ngcontent-wwl-c681="" mat-button="" class="mat-focus-indicator mat-button mat-button-base mat-primary mat-raised-button" ng-reflect-color="primary" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-ng-class="mat-raised-button">
        <span class="mat-button-wrapper">
            <button
                _ngcontent-wwl-c681=""
                mat-button=""
                class="mat-focus-indicator mat-button mat-button-base mat-primary mat-raised-button ng-scope"
                ng-reflect-color="primary"
                ng-reflect-disabled="false"
                ng-reflect-ng-class="mat-raised-button"
            >
                <span class="mat-button-wrapper"> User Security Report </span>
                <span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></span><span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span>
            </button>
        </span>
        <span matripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-button-ripple" ng-reflect-disabled="false" ng-reflect-centered="false" ng-reflect-trigger="[object HTMLButtonElement]"></span><span class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></span>
    </button>
</cb-button>
```

EDIT:

When i remove the ***downgrade*** decorator from the module it works as expected:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: ButtonComponent,
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        CbPopupTipModule,
        CbClickModule
    ],
    exports: ButtonComponent
})
@CbDowngrades({
    components: [
        { selector: 'cb-button', component: ButtonComponent }
    ]
})
export class CbButtonModule { }
```

The code used to do the downgrade:

```
import { downgradeComponent, downgradeInjectable } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { ClassCtor } from '../types/classctor.type';
import { NGJS_APP_NAME } from '../declarations/app.constants';
import { kebabCaseToCamelCase } from 'cb-hub-lib';

const DOWNGRADE_MODULE = angular.module(NGJS_APP_NAME);

function cbDowngradeComponent(ngJsSelector: string, componentClass: ClassCtor): void {
    DOWNGRADE_MODULE
        .directive(
            ngJsSelector,
            downgradeComponent({ component: componentClass })
        );
}

function cbDowngradeInjectable(ngJsInjectionToken: string, injectableClass: ClassCtor): void {
    DOWNGRADE_MODULE
        .factory(ngJsInjectionToken, downgradeInjectable(injectableClass));
}

function cbDowngradeComponents(components: CbDowngradeComponent[] = []): void {
    components.forEach((component) => {
        const camelCaseSelector = kebabCaseToCamelCase(component.selector);
        cbDowngradeComponent(camelCaseSelector, component.component);
    });
}

function cbDowngradeInjectables(injectables: (ClassCtor | CbDowngradeInjectable)[] = []): void {
    injectables.forEach((injectable) => {
        if ((injectable as ClassCtor).name) {
            const injectableCtor = (injectable as ClassCtor);
            cbDowngradeInjectable(injectableCtor.name, injectableCtor);
        } else {
            const injectableConfig = (injectable as CbDowngradeInjectable);
            cbDowngradeInjectable(injectableConfig.token, injectableConfig.injectable);
        }
    });
}
interface CbDowngrades {
    components?: CbDowngradeComponent[];
    injectables?: CbDowngradeInjectable[];
}

interface CbDowngradeInjectable {
    /** ThisShouldBePascalCase */
    token: string;
    injectable: ClassCtor;
}

interface CbDowngradeComponent {
    /** this-should-be-kebab-case */
    selector: string;
    component: ClassCtor;
}

/** Decorate your modules with this decorator to downgrade any components or injectables for usage in angularjs
 */
export function CbDowngrades(cbDowngrades: CbDowngrades): ClassDecorator {
    return (constructor: Function) => {
        cbDowngradeComponents(cbDowngrades.components);
        cbDowngradeInjectables(cbDowngrades.injectables);
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi @BeniaminoBaggins, you're using the "single-slot content projection": https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#single-slot-content-projection. I guess you're using your <cb-button> with a <button> tag inside. If not, check what's on the button underneath by using the developer tools of your browser and tell us. Also it would help to have more exact source code from your source.

Comment: Hi @JanosVinceller, I have now added the produced html to the bottom of the question. Also see "using it:" to see what I am passing into the `ng-content`. Also I have simplified the html template which still produces the error, and yes the html template has <button> in it. Thanks!